# Cloth simulation not deforming properly with hooks

Tags: physics, cloth-simulation, hook-modifier

I have a low poly mesh with a cloth sash that I'm trying to drape on.

Most of the hooks in the cloth simulation work great but for some reason the top of the robe acts strange and just arcs in the air. I've checked the vertex groups and hooks assigned and they all seem to be correct. I've played with the stiffness thinking that it might be the problem but I can't seem to understand. It feels like rotation more or less is okay but any translation just wrecks the model.

[image]

Here's a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=InLlCpTkF8k) of the problem

[image]

Comment: At a rough guess it looks like your hook isn't parented to the model's main armature or main parent (handle) if it's got one.  i.e. is it being left behind?

Comment: The hook is parented to a vertex on the mesh. Really the problem is the arcing around the hook, because the actual vertices of the cloth attached to the hook move fine but it just stops acting like cloth

Comment: It could be a conflict between the Hook and cloth/physics engines.  I;m on an old machine with linux here but will go offline and see if I can get the same problem.   I can't recall if the cloth physics also appears in the modifier stack as do the hook modifiers.  If so you could try changing their order of appearance, move the hook or cloth modifier up above the other.

Comment: Hey thanks for taking a deeper look into it. So originally I had No Falloff so the radius wasn't really an option, I enabled it and set it to 'Smooth' and tried it at 0, 0.5, 1, and 2 and it still seems to yield the same results.

Comment: I can give you my own Blend file to see how mine works, but I wonder if you shouldn't be asking again for someone to take a look at yours.  I'm on an older version of Blender and wouldn't be able to load anything above 2.8

Comment: I think there's probably some good explanation I'm not thinking of or don't have the blender background to understand but I'll probably just scrap the cloth sim and do the animation manually unfortunately. Thanks for all your help though.

Comment: Certainly, learning to manually animate the cape with hooks curves or whatever will teach you skills that will become most useful further along, but learning to use the cloth sim will most likely be equally important.


With this in mind, I've posted up an ultra simple example to show how a cape can be placed on an individual's shoulders and with a hook added after to lift a part of the cape back from the model where and if that's required. Try doing it that way yourself, if only to demonstrate in your mind that it can work.  It can be set up in a short time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For BSE -

I've put this up as an ultra simple but detailed example and suggest that you try this before giving up.  It's useful to know how to use the cloth sim anyway.

To play the Blend file, try ALT-A if loading in the source UI.

Use CTL left & right to switch windows.

-=================-

Simple cape & hook

[image]

Try setting up a simple scene with a vertical cylinder for the character's torso - make it a 'Collision' object and drape a cloth cape around it's upper area.  (Pin and shape the upper edge and use the cloth's default settings initially)

--->  Make sure to TURN OFF Proportional Editing <---

Set the cylinder/torso's Origin point to it's bottom surface and keyframe it's rotation so it bends over.

Parent the cloth mesh to it with CTL-P --> "Keep Transform' and watch it rotate again, see what the cloth does.

If it's ok, (ignore any clipping) add a 'Graduated Hook'  at frame 1...

Details -

Select the cloth, and in Edit mode, highlight ALL vertices including the pinned group.

Back in object mode -

Add an Empty near the back of the cloth but not on it.  Scale the Empty and use CTL-A to apply it's smaller size. (scale it as 1.0)

With it still selected, hold Shift down and also select the cloth.  Both should be highlited.

Go into Edit mode and see that -->  ALL <-- of the cloth's vertices are still highlited.

Press CTL-H --> "Selected Object".

---> Don't play the animation yet <---

Back in Object mode, select the cloth again and open it's modifier list.  In the 'Hook" modifier, set it's radius to something above zero. (0.5?)  That will stop it wanting to drag the entire cloth as a whole.

In the viewport, select the hook again and drag it out from the cloth - see what happens.  If it's working properly, only a small section of the cloth will be pulled back and much like proportional editing.
i.e. radially and graduated by distance.  Try different radius settings.

Parent the hook to the cylinder with CTL-P --> 'Keep transform' and then play the animation, watch what happens when the torso rotates.  The cloth and Hook should both follow the torso's rotation without affecting how the Hook affects the cloth.

Set the viewport's Transformation axis to "Normal".  (Menu in the window header)

When the Hook is moved at any frame, it's operation should lift the cloth back independently.

[image]